# How to test the login func in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I write this according to flaskr sample, I can login with browser,but test fails. Thanks for your help!

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if lib.authenticate_user(username, password):
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return render_template('www.html') 
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

tests.py

```
def login(self, username, password):
    #print username, password
    return self.app.post('/Login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)


# testing functions


def test_login_logout(self):
    """Make sure login and logout works"""
    rv = self.login('c1','123')
    assert 'You were logged in' in rv.data
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to change this part in tests.py:

```
return self.app.post('/Login', data=dict(
```

to this one:

```
return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
```

Capitalisation matters!